# PHPMailer send template in body failed

Tags: phpmailer

I need to send a template in my mail->body, but in the mail returned, i don't have my template but '1'.

If i do an echo of my template, my template is show good :

```
$template = require('../../template/newsletter/template_1.php');
echo $template;
```

And the fail is when i try to call my template in $mail->body like this :

```
$mail->Body = $template;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` a value from the template file, just requiring it isn't enough. As [the docs say](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1.

Note in particular example 5 on that page:

```php
return.php
<?php

$var = 'PHP';

return $var;

?>

noreturn.php
<?php

$var = 'PHP';

?>

testreturns.php
<?php

$foo = include 'return.php';

echo $foo; // prints 'PHP'

$bar = include 'noreturn.php';

echo $bar; // prints 1

?>
```

So make sure you have a `return` statement in your template file, or have it output content and capture it with [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php). Alternatively, use a templating system that does this for you such as Smarty or Twig.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine with return !